# When i try to save an image on Emulator, it says:"There was an error saving the image"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Using Eclipse's AVD Emulator, when i try to save an image to Gallery in an app that i'm testing, it shows a toast with the message:"There was an error saving the image". I tested on two AVDs and the result was like this; Though when i used a phone connected through USB there was not such problem and it worked properly.

How can i solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

update:

Ok. This is the logcat for a time i tried to save an image:

07-21 15:02:02.092: D/ConnectivityService(395): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
07-21 15:02:02.132: D/ConnectivityService(395): Done.
07-21 15:02:02.132: D/ConnectivityService(395): Setting timer for 720seconds
07-21 15:02:51.382: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.382: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.382: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.382: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.392: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.392: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.392: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.392: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.392: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.392: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.392: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.402: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.402: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.402: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.402: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.402: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.402: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.402: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.442: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.442: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-21 15:02:51.452: W/AudioService(395): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
07-21 15:02:51.632: W/EGL_emulation(1200): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-21 15:02:58.012: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.012: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.012: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.022: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.022: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.022: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.022: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.022: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.022: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.022: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.022: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.042: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.052: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.052: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.052: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.062: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.062: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.062: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.072: E/SoundPool(395): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.072: W/AudioService(395): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-21 15:02:58.072: W/AudioService(395): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200): Failed to insert image
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:611)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:922)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:669)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:902)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at com.deitel.doodlz.DoodleView.saveImage(DoodleView.java:274)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at com.deitel.doodlz.DoodleFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(DoodleFragment.java:172)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:1806)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:1972)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2603)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:748)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:891)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:881)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-21 15:02:58.172: E/MediaStore(1200):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 15:02:58.232: D/MediaProvider(484): object removed 34
07-21 15:02:58.322: W/InputMethodManagerService(395): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b1f55d38 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b1face20

Comment: problem for sd card probably

Comment: Then use Actual device why used AVD?